# MIPS forwarding implementation (tough)

Tags: mips, mips32, mips64

I think I understand the first part
(i). I at least have answers for this. I am not sure about where this implementation would fail though, for part ii? Part ii has me completely stumped. Does anyone know situations where this would fail?

If you want to shine some light on part iii you would be my entire classes hero. Were all stumped there. Thanks for any input.

*Tim FlimFlam, the infamous architect of the MN-4363 processor, is struggling with a pipelined implementation of the basic MIPS ISA.*

(i) To implement forwarding, Tim connected the output of logic from EX and MEM stages (these logic outputs represent inputs to EXMEM and MEMWB latches, respectively) to the input of IDEX register. He claims that he will be able to cover any dependency in this manner.
• Would this implementation work?
• Would he need to insert any muxes? Explain for
1. the producer instruction is a load.
2. the producer instruction is of R-type. 3. the consumer instruction is of R-type. 4. the consumer instruction is a branch. 5. the consumer instruction is a store.

(ii) Tim claims that forwarding to EX stage only suffices to cover all dependencies.
• Provide two examples where his implementation would fail.
• Would “fail” in this case correspond to breaking correctness constraints?

(iii) Tim tries to identify the minimum amount of information to be transferred acros pipeline stages. Considering R-type, data transfer, and branch instructions, explain how wide each pipeline register should be, demarcating different fields per latch.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is late, but the answer rests in "all dependencies" in part 2. Dependencies/hazards are of multiple types, viz, control, data. Some data hazards can be fixed by forwarding (from the MEM && WB stages to execute stage. Other data hazards like LOAD dependency is not possible to fix by forwarding. To see why this happens, note that a LOAD instruction in the MEM stage will have the output ready from the memory only in the end of that clock cycle. In that same clock cycle, any intstruction in the execute stage which requires the value of the LOAD instruction will get the incorrect value. In such a scenario, at any instant of time within the clock cycle say beginning, the alu is beginning to execute while the memory is 'beginning' to fetch the data. At the end of the cycle, while the memory has finished fetching the data, the alu has also finished computing with the wrong values. To prevent hazards, you need alu to be beginning computing while the data memory has finished fetching (i.e the alu must stall for 1 cycle or you must have a nop between LOAD and ALU instrcution. Hope this helps!